Testing dependency call args in FastAPI
I have an api with a route that creates google cloud tasks. I import the task client as dependency into the endpoint. I mocked the task client in my tests with app.dependency_overrides but now I'm not sure how to use that in order to see the call args for the send_task_to_queue function. In my old flask api I could just patch send_task_to_queue and check its call_args but trying that here is giving me None
# TASK CLIENT
class TasksClient:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # sets up client

    def send_task_to_queue(
            self,
            queue: str,
            task_func: str,
            payload: Any  # payload can be anything
    ) -> None:
        # creates task - want to check the queue, task_func, and payload args


@lru_cache
def get_tasks_client() -> TasksClient:
    return TasksClient()


# ENDPOINT
@router.post("/route",
             status_code=201,
             description="POST to route")
async def post_inspection(
        req: Request,
        tasks_client: TasksClient = Depends(get_tasks_client)
) -> None:
    tasks_client.send_task_to_queue('queue_name', 'task_func_name', 'payload')


# MOCK CLASSES
class MockGoogleTaskClient(object):
    """ Mock tasks client from google """
    @staticmethod
    def queue_path(project_id, loc, queue):
        return f'{project_id}.{loc}.{queue}'

    @staticmethod
    def create_task(path, task):
        return


class MockTasksClient(object):
    """ mock tasks class """
    def __init__(self):
        self.credentials = 'creds'
        self.client = MockGoogleTaskClient()

    @staticmethod
    def send_task_to_queue(queue, task_func, payload):
        """ mock send task to queue """
        return


def mock_get_tasks_client() -> MockTasksClient:
    return MockTasksClient()


# CONFTEST
from api.main import app
app.dependency_overrides[get_tasks_client] = mock_get_tasks_client


# TEST
# doesn't work - get None
@patch('api.util.tasks.get_tasks_client', side_effect=mock_get_tasks_client)
def test_post_inspection(
        m_tasks_client,
        client: TestClient,
        engine: Engine
) -> None:
    happy_insert_resp = client.post(f'route', json={'hello': 'test'})
    assert happy_insert_resp.status_code == 201

    # make sure tasks are created
    assert m_tasks_client.send_task_to_queue.call_args == ???  # comes in as None


can you try to patch the location from where get_tasks_client is called, and not defined? like the one where you have defined the route
